# How to have or condition on a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How to have or condition on this repeat ?

I want to filter this tbody depending of a value

MY TABLE

```
                        <tbody ng-repeat="Fund in ListTask | filter:{CreationDate: manager.start}:true | filter:{DueDate: manager.end}:true | filter:{Beneficiary: currentNode.name}:true  | filter:{Title: currentNode.name}:true  | filter:{category: currentNode.name}:true">
                        <tr ng-dblclick="open(Fund.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{Fund.type}}">
                            <td>{{Fund.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Beneficiary}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Title}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.status}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.category}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.CreationDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{FormField.shortDate(Fund.DueDate)}}</td>
                            <td>{{Fund.Team}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to implement your own filter.

Example :

```
.filter('specialFilter', function() {
    return function(funds,manager,currentNode) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(funds, function(fund) {
            if (fund.CreationDate ==manager.start|| fund.category==currentNode.name)
                   filtered.push(fund);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
})

<tbody ng-repeat="Fund in ListTask | specialFilter:manager:currentNode"
```

To notice, if you have an important number of funds (>2000), it could be better for performances to build yourself a specific array of data filtered.

Comment: I do have an error it say that  Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Comment: It seems your variable manager is undefined.
As you understood : Fund in ListTask | specialFilter:manager:currentNode allow to call filter 'specialFilter' with arguments 'manager' and 'currentNode'. They have to be defined.
Maybe it's not always the case in your scope ? You should add an "if" inside the filter : if (manager && currentNode) .

Comment: You succeed to implement it ?